# Сложная выборка из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 массива массивов, 1 с городами а 2 с категориями:

```
 $cities = array(
    'Брестская область' => array(
       'Брест', 'Барановичи', 'Береза', 'Ганцевичи',
       'Дрогичин' ,'Жабинка' ,'Иваново', 'Ивацевичи',
       'Каменец' ,'Кобрин', 'Лунинец', 'Ляховичи',
       'Малорита' ,'Пинск', 'Пружаны', 'Столин',
       'Брестская область'),
    'Витебская область' => array(
       'Витебск','Бешенковичи', 'Браслав', 'Верхнедвинск',
       'Глубокое', 'Городок', 'Докшицы', 'Дубровно',
       'Лепель', 'Лиозно', 'Миоры', 'Орша', 'Полоцк',
       'Поставы', 'Россоны', 'Сенно', 'Толочин', 'Ушачи',
       'Чашники', 'Шарковщина', 'Шумилино', 'Витебская область'),
    'Гомельская область' => array(
       'Гомель', 'Брагин', 'Буда-Кошелево', 'Ветка',
       'Добруш', 'Ельск', 'Житковичи', 'Жлобин',
       'Калинковичи', 'Корма', 'Лельчицы', 'Лоев',
       'Мозырь', 'Наровля', 'Октябрьский', 'Петриков',
       'Речица', 'Рогачев', 'Светлогорск', 'Хойники',
       'Чечерск', 'Гомельская область'),
    'Гродненская область' => array(
       'Гродно', 'Берестовица', 'Волковыск', 'Вороново',
       'Дятлово', 'Зельва', 'Ивье', 'Кореличи',
       'Лида', 'Мосты', 'Новогрудок', 'Островец',
       'Ошмяны', 'Свислочь', 'Слоним', 'Сморгонь',
       'Щучин', 'Гродненская область'),
    'Минская область' => array(
       'Минск', 'Березино', 'Борисов', 'Вилейка',
       'Воложин', 'Дзержинск', 'Жодино', 'Клецк',
       'Копыль', 'Крупки', 'Логойск', 'Любань',
       'Марьина Горка', 'Молодечно', 'Мядель', 
       'Несвиж', 'Слуцк', 'Смолевичи', 'Солигорск', 
       'Старые Дороги', 'Столбцы', 'Узда',
       'Червень', 'Минская область'),
    'Могилёвская область' => array(
       'Могилев', 'Белыничи', 'Бобруйск', 'Быхов', 
       'Глуск', 'Горки', 'Дрибин', 'Кировск', 'Климовичи',
       'Кличев', 'Костюковичи', 'Краснополье', 'Кричев',
       'Круглое', 'Мстиславль', 'Осиповичи', 'Славгород', 
       'Хотимск', 'Чаусы', 'Чериков', 'Шклов', 'Могилёвская область')
  );

  $categors = array(
    'Детский мир' => array(
       'Детский мир', 'Детская одежда', 'Детская обувь', 
       'Детские коляски', 'Детские автокресла', 'Детская мебель',
       'Игрушки', 'Детский транспорт', 'Товары для кормления', 'Товары для школьников',
       'Прочие детские товары'),
    'Недвижимость' => array(
       'Недвижимость','Аренда квартир','Аренда комнат',
       'Аренда домов','Аренда земли','Аренда гаражей / Стоянок',
       'Ищу компаньона','Продажа квартир','Продажа комнат',
       'Продажа домов', 'Продажа земли','Продажа гаражей / Стоянок',
       'Аренда помещений','Продажа помещений','Прочая недвижимость',
       'Обмен недвижимости'),
    'Транспорт' => array(
      'Транспорт','Легковые автомобили','Мото','Автобусы',
      'Спецтехника','Грузовые автомобили','Сельхозтехника',
      'Водный транспорт','Воздушный транспорт','Запчасти / Аксессуары',
      'Прицепы','Другой транспорт','Авто / Мото услуги'),
    'Работа' => array(
      'Работа','Розничная торговля / Продажи','Транспорт / Логистика',
      'Строительство','Бары / Рестораны','Юриспруденция и Бухгалтерия',
      'Охрана / Безопасность','Домашний персонал','Красота / Фитнес / Спорт',
      'Туризм / Отдых / Развлечения','Образование','Культура / Искусство',
      'Медицина / Фармация','ИТ / Телеком / Компьютеры','Недвижимость',
      'Маркетинг / Реклама / Дизайн','Производство / Энергетика',
      'Cекретариат / АХО','Частичная занятость','Начало карьеры / Студенты',
      'Сервис и Быт','Другие сферы занятий'),
    'Животные' => array(
     'Животные','Собаки','Кошки','Аквариумистика',
     'Птицы','Грызуны','Рептилии','Сельхоз животные',
     'Животные даром','Зоотовары','Вязка','Бюро находок',
     'Другие животные'),
    'Дом и Сад' => array(
       'Дом и Сад','Канцтовары / Расходные материалы',
       'Мебель','Предметы интерьера','Строительство / Ремонт',
       'Инструменты','Комнатные Растения','Посуда / Кухонная утварь',
       'Садовый Инвентарь','Сад / Огород','Хозяйственный инвентарь / Бытовая химия',
       'Прочие товары для дома'),
     'Электроника' => array(
        'Электроника','Телефоны','Компьютеры',
        'Фото / Видео','Тв / Видеотехника','Аудиотехника',
        'Игры и Игровые приставки','Техника для дома',
        'Техника для кухни','Климатическое оборудование','Индивидуальный уход',
        'Аксессуары и комплектующие','Прочая электроника'),
      'Услуги / Бизнес' => array(
            'Услуги / Бизнес','Строительство / Ремонт / Уборка',
            'Финансовые услуги / Партнерство','Перевозки / Аренда транспорта',
            'Реклама / Полиграфия / Маркетинг / Интернет','Няни / Сиделки',
            'Сырьё / материалы','Красота / Здоровье','Оборудование','Образование / Спорт',
            'Услуги для животных','Продажа бизнеса','Развлечение / Искусство / Фото / Видео',
            'Туризм / Иммиграция','Услуги переводчиков / Набор текста','Авто / Мото услуги',
            'Обслуживание, Ремонт техники','Сетевой маркетинг','Юридические услуги',
            'Прокат товаров','Прочие услуги'),
        'Мода и Cтиль' => array(
            'Мода и Cтиль','Одежда/обувь','Для свадьбы',
            'Мода разное','Наручные часы','Аксессуары',
            'Подарки','Красота / Здоровье'),
        'Хобби, Отдых и Спорт' => array(
            'Хобби, Отдых и Спорт','Антиквариат / Коллекции',
            'Музыкальные инструменты','Другое','Спорт / Отдых',
            'Книги / Журналы','CD / DVD / Пластинки / Кассеты',
'Билеты','Поиск попутчиков','Поиск групп / Музыкантов')
  );
```

Далее код которым я сортирую вывод в зависимости от полученных данных:

```
if(isset($_GET["city"])) {
    $city = htmlspecialchars($_GET["city"]);
    $city = trim ($city);
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь') {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT 12";
    } elseif(array_key_exists($city, $cities)) {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE city IN ('" . implode("','", $cities[$city]) . "')
                  ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
                  LIMIT 12";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE city = '$city'
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT 12";
    }
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}

if(isset($_GET["categor"])) {
    $categor = htmlspecialchars($_GET["categor"]);
    $categor = trim ($categor);
    if($categor == 'Все категории') {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT 12";
    } elseif(array_key_exists($categor, $categors)) {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE categor IN ('" . implode("','", $categors[$categor]) . "')
                  ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
                  LIMIT 12";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE categor = '$categor'
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT 12";
    }
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

Дело в том что данный код сортирует поля по отдельности, то есть они не знают о существовании друг друга. Следующий код немного исправляет эту ситуацию:

```
if( isset($_GET["city"]) and isset($_GET["categor"]) ) {
    $city = htmlspecialchars($_GET["city"]);
    $city = trim ($city);
    $categor = htmlspecialchars($_GET["categor"]);
    $categor = trim ($categor);
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь' and $categor == 'Все категории')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE categor = '$categor' ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($categor == 'Все категории')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city = '$city' && categor = '$categor' ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
}
```

Данный код сортирует данные учитывая 2 введенных поля, НО, не учитывает если выбрали целый массив например (Брестская область)~(Недвижимость), помогите пожалуйста сделать что бы учитывался выбор массивов.

Дайте пример как это можно сделать а дальше я попытаюсь сделать по аналогии.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего ввести массив `$where` в который добавлять условия проверки, по мере прохождения логики скрипта

```
<?php
...
$where = array();
...
$where[] = "city = '$city'";
...
$where[] = "categor = '$categor'";
```

А в конце скрипта, когда все условия будут собраны, просто объедините их при помощи ключевого слова `AND`

```
if (count($where) > 0 ) {
  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM `articles`
            WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where) . "
            ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
            LIMIT 12";
} else {
  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM `articles`
            ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
            LIMIT 12";
}
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю. Вот так? 
https://jsfiddle.net/3r4b8150/

Comment: Если я всё правильно сделал то у меня теперь учитывается 2 поля НО если я выберу целый массив (Вся область) то оно не выводит ничего.
Вот я выбираю Аренда квартир -> Брест = все выводит, но когда Аренда квартир -> Брестская область = ничего

Comment: Или будет выводить если я только при добавлении записи явно укажу вся область, то оно выведет не потому что сравнивает массив а из-за сравнивания переменных